# Migrating all features of store in Volusion to Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I’m facing a large number of different problems with my Volusion cart now. What I was thinking of is moving to Magento. The thing is, I want to move not only products, customers and orders but also SEO URLs. So, I’m wondering if there is some extension that would do this? Will be grateful for any ideas!

Comment: why wont you check magento connect??

Comment: There's really not a great answer to this question as it is highly dependent on your setup, data, etc. For this reason any answer would also likely not benefit others. It's therefore best to ask your question over at the [Magento Forums](http://community.magento.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For importing you would need to do the following:

**Products:** Magento out of the box, I have found is not the best for importing products. I do however recommend using [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) to import products.

This can deal with the most complex product types and comes with a load of extensions. It is also very fast for importing products but it can take time for getting your product CSV files ready for importing depending on the complexity of your catalog.

*You also specify the URL of the product for SEO purposes too with this plugin*.

**Customers:** In Magento, can import customers using its "Customer Import" Database profile place which you can find under System -> Import/Export -> Database Profiles.

**Orders:** This is very tricky and you need to use a paid extension. I have only attempted to import orders once and I found it quite hard due to the EAV system used in Magento.